# Sharing an internet proxy as a router input

Tags: windows, proxy, vpn, routers

I want to share a Windows LAN proxy as input for a router. A VPN service makes this proxy.
internet -> router1 -> windows -> *(proxy -> router2) -> System2
I implement the scenario with a VPN by sharing the VPN adapter with router2.
In proxy mode, I have no adapter for sharing the net.
The proxy is set on Lan -> Proxy. I don't have access to its credentials.
Router1: mi gig
Router2: Asus RT-AC86U
Both system operations: Windows
Proxy type: HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Tor looks like one of possible solutions: you can utilize it's TransPort functionality and launch the Tor itself through an upstream HTTP proxy, this will work. And your `router2` must be set as a client of TransPort transparent proxy to make it work. To make things easier to set up - use a USB ethernet that you'll pass through to a VirtualBox machine with Tor and transparent proxy, it will make things a way easier to set up